# Desktop becoming unresponsive at random times

Tags: hard-drive, freeze

I'm kinda suspecting the HDD as the cause since whenever something **randomly** goes **"not responding"** and then try to call for Task Manager, it doesn't come out until it responds again. Another thing is that when I tried to boot into safe mode, the problem still occurs and not to mention that no errors are shown in the **Event Viewer**

What I really want to know is if there is something I can do to fix the problem without reformatting or buying a new one (and use it as the system)?

And also, if I do need to resort to buying a new one, then would it be possible to keep the hard drive without causing those unresponsiveness to occur?
(Well, not on the system anyway... if it occurs only to that drive, then I guess it's bearable?)

Comment: Definitely related, possibly a duplicate: [Why do damaged hard drives freeze entire system?](http://superuser.com/q/954262/53590)

Comment: Yes, it is related judging from my 2nd question **(which is about transferring or using data from a rather faulty drive from a good drive)** but it's either I'm not too well versed with how this works or just can't understand at all...
What my main question was if there was a way to fix this without resorting to reformatting or buying a new one to replace it.

Answer (score 0):

Drives will sometimes mark sectors as bad and not use them. That being said, if you have a hard drive which has bad sectors, replacement of the drive is the only real answer.

Sure, you may be able to limp along, but it is only a matter of time before the situation worsens.

Booting you system using an Ubuntu CD will allow you to run the smart tests in the disks program. This will often show the true health of the drive when Windows event viewer shows no issue.