# Why the whole system hangs while trying to reading bad CD/DVD?

Tags: windows-7, compact-disc

When I insert some scratched CDs or DVDs and try to read them, the whole operating system (Win7 in my case) seems to hang. Looks like all hard drive I/O is also paralized and most Windows OS hangs. Why does this happens? Is there any other OS or configuration that does not have this issue?

I'm unable to test this on my newer systems because they dont have optical drives...

This may be related to either Windows architecture, the driver model, a problem with PATA/SATA design, but I am not sure which one is the culprit.

Comment: Possibly hardware from my experience, if possible its worth connecting the disk drive to a SATA III port if its currently connected to a SATA II port, but then it could be SATA driver related too so perhaps you can look at updating the SATA driver too - check in device manager for "Standard Dual Channel PCI IDE Controller", if you see it then that could be part of the problem (generic drivers can cause all sorts of problems).

Comment: So, this is a problem with how SATA and IDE works. A bad CD or a bad hard drive has the same symptoms so thanks for providing the link to the other question which has a great explanation: http://superuser.com/questions/954262/why-do-damaged-hard-drives-freeze-the-entire-system

Comment: Good find there, hope it helps!