# My system becomes slow when HDD is under 100% load even though it runs on an SSD which is on ~5%

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, ssd, speed

I installed the operating system and all my main programs on an SSD, but the memory is just not big enough for everything, so I use an HDD in addition to my SSD.

When I'm copying something on HDD, installing games on HDD or anything else that causes HDD to be under 100% load, my system becomes really slow even though the SSD is on really on like 5-10%.

Specs:

- HDD: WD 1TB, 7200RPM, 64MB of cache (wd10ezex)
- SSD: SSD SATA3 120GB Kingston A400 500/320MB/s
- CPU: Ryzen 5 2600 @ 6C/12T, 3.4-3.9GHz
- RAM: 8GB, 2400MHz
- mobo: ASUS Prime 350B-PLUS

Comment: Find a way to throttle thr speed of the copy. Your ability to do this will depend on the software you are using.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't quite understand you... Can you be more specific?

Comment: no. Your question lacks sufficient detail. The problem is clearly that the hdd writes are.consuming all the resources. The solution is to reduce the speed of the writes to free up resources - how you do that depends on your software and requirements.

Comment: Well, but still I think you don't understand me. I'm asking why is my system being slow while HDD is under load even if I have SSD that is NOT under load. It should not be happening, right, since my OS and 90% of programs are installed on SSD.

Comment: I understand you. Your hard drive is blocking IO and slowing down the system. (I cant help that this is normal but you dont think so. Also the location of data not being accessed is irrelevant). There are a few reasons for this - mainly a limitation of the SATA standard and a bit to do with theOS. Have a read of the accepted answer of https://superuser.com/questions/954262/why-do-damaged-hard-drives-freeze-the-entire-system and consider that a busy hdd is analogous to a dying one.